# Avro - code-generation approach vs non-code generation approach

Tags: java, scala, serialization, avro, spark-avro

I'm new to Avro. The official [documentation](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/gettingstartedjava.html) indicates that there are two possible approaches to using avro;

- With code generation - here classes are auto-generated from avro schema files by the avro compiler. These classes are then used in the application code.
- Without code generation - the schemas are directly parsed in the application. Instead of using auto-generated classes (as in the first approach), the application creates `GenericRecord` objects instead.

**Question**

- What are the pros and cons of each approach (eg: in terms of performance, ease  of writing the application code, etc.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, the main thing to remember is code generation rules! If you are not generating it, mean you are like doing it badly! Totaly!